# How underlying apache cache works

Tags: caching, apache2

We have enabled disk cache in apache2.4, but AFAIK, client browser has his own cache as well.

In this case how can i test the Apache2 cache actually is holding my image file but not the browser?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and/or use porn mode. If the asset is still cached, it's not in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, however once I use incognito mode from Chrome, my image is always getting 200 directly from server.  How can make it hit my cache in my apache cache? My configurations as below:  <br/>


inline `CacheRoot /tmp/apacheCache . <br/>
CacheEnable disk / . <br/>
CacheDirLevels 5 . <br/>
CacheDirLength 3`

Comment: I read through some documents, then it looks to me, the browser cache is related to haeder/expire module. And the cache module we are talking here is something Linux server caching, this is to reduce the IO time on read the physical files from disk (or even remote server) directly. Appreciate if anyone can confirm my understanding is correct.